# Find a cell value, look up corresponding code in another sheet and copy multiple values that correspond

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel "Sheet4" that looks like this:

```
Name    Cost   Code   Type
Item 1   $10           A
Item 2     -    PR6    A
Item 3   $15           B
Item 4     -    PR2    B
Item 5   $15           B
```

Then a second "Sheet3" that looks like this:

```
Code  PR6
CLR   $10   GRY   $12   BRN   $12
GRN   $12   RED   $13   GRX   $17

Code  PR2
CLR   $12   GRY   $14   BRN   $14
GRN   $14   RED   $14   GRX   $20
```

What I need to do is build a macro to look up the codes for the blank price values in sheet1 and copy multiple prices for different colors from sheet2 so that the final readout in sheet1 would look like this:

```
Name    Cost   Code   Type
Item 1   $10           A
Item 2   $10    CLR    A
Item 2   $12    GRY    A
Item 2   $17    GYX    A
Item 3   $15           B
Item 4   $12    CLR    B
Item 4   $14    GRY    B
Item 4   $20    GYX    B
Item 5   $15           B
```

All of the colors and prices in sheet2 are in separate cells.

I will only need the same colors for each one (ie will need to copy CLR, GRY and GYX) but there will be certain groups in sheet2 that don't have one of the needed colors (one may only have CLR and GYX without GRY).

I've tried the code below but I think it's having a hard time because I am referencing a cell in the "item" range using Offset and it says "object doesn't support this property or method". I need to be able to paste the values I am getting from Sheet3 into the right columns in Sheet4; columns B and C respectively.

If I can get the code below to work, the only thing I'll have left to do is add Elseif statements for each corresponding color and then make it insert rows and copy the lines to fill.

Sub productsTest()

```
Dim st1, st2 As Worksheet
Set st1 = Sheets("Sheet4")
Set st2 = Sheets("Sheet3")
Dim items As Range
Set items = st1.Range(st1.Range("A1"), st1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Dim item As Range

For Each item In items
    Dim cost As String
    Dim code As String
    Dim t As String
    cost = item.Offset(0, 1).Value
    code = item.Offset(0, 2).Value
    t = item.Offset(0, 3).Value
    If cost = "0" Then
        Dim prodPos As Range
        Dim prodColors As Range
        Dim prodColor As Range
        Dim colorcost As String
        Dim color As String

        Set prodPos = st2.Cells.Find(What:=code, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        Set prodColors = Range(prodPos.Offset(1, -1), prodPos.Offset(6, 6))

        For Each prodColor In prodColors
            If prodColor.Value = "CLR" Then
                color = prodColor.Value
                colorcost = prodColor.Offset(0, 1).Value
                   'This is where its encountering a problem
                Worksheets("Sheet4").item.Offset(0, 2).Activate
                ActiveCell.Value = color
                st1.item.Offset(0, 1).Value = colorcost
            End If
        Next prodColor

    End If
Next item
```

End Sub

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results (From: [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)). See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). So make a beginning with your code, post it, and tell us where you're stuck.

Comment: Sorry about this, because I am trying to do so many things in a sequence I've been a little overwhelmed every time I try and get into it. I am going to work a little with what brWHigino posted and edit my post as I make a little progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out:

```
Sub productsTest()

Dim st1, st2 As Worksheet
Set st1 = Sheets("Sheet4")
Set st2 = Sheets("Sheet3")
Dim items As Range
Set items = st1.Range(st1.Range("A1"), st1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Dim item As Range

For Each item In items
    Dim cost As String
    Dim code As String
    Dim R As Long
    Dim C As Long
    item.Activate
    R = ActiveCell.Row
    C = ActiveCell.Column
    cost = item.Offset(0, 1).Value
    code = item.Offset(0, 2).Value
    If cost = "0" Then
        Dim prodPos As Range
        Dim prodColors As Range
        Dim prodColor As Range
        Dim colorcost As String
        Dim color As String

        Set prodPos = st2.Cells.Find(What:=code, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        Set prodColors = Range(prodPos.Offset(1, -1), prodPos.Offset(6, 6))

        'I added a For statement for each color
        For Each prodColor In prodColors
            If prodColor.Value = "CLR" Then
                color = prodColor.Value
                colorcost = prodColor.Offset(0, 1).Value
                st1.Cells(R, C).Offset(0, 2).Value = color
                st1.Cells(R, C).Offset(0, 1).Value = colorcost
            End If
        Next prodColor
        For Each prodColor In prodColors
            If prodColor.Value = "PGX" Then
                color = prodColor.Value
                colorcost = prodColor.Offset(0, 1).Value
                st1.Range("A" & R & ":D" & R).Select
                Selection.Copy
                Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                st1.Cells(R, C).Offset(0, 2).Value = color
                st1.Cells(R, C).Offset(0, 1).Value = colorcost
            End If
        Next prodColor
        For Each prodColor In prodColors
            If prodColor.Value = "TGY" Then
                color = prodColor.Value
                colorcost = prodColor.Offset(0, 1).Value
                st1.Range("A" & R & ":D" & R).Select
                Selection.Copy
                Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                st1.Cells(R, C).Offset(0, 2).Value = color
                st1.Cells(R, C).Offset(0, 1).Value = colorcost
            End If
        Next prodColor
                    For Each prodColor In prodColors
            If prodColor.Value = "TVG" Then
                color = prodColor.Value
                colorcost = prodColor.Offset(0, 1).Value
                st1.Range("A" & R & ":D" & R).Select
                Selection.Copy
                Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                st1.Cells(R, C).Offset(0, 2).Value = color
                st1.Cells(R, C).Offset(0, 1).Value = colorcost
            End If
        Next prodColor
                    For Each prodColor In prodColors
            If prodColor.Value = "GYC" Then
                color = prodColor.Value
                colorcost = prodColor.Offset(0, 1).Value
                st1.Range("A" & R & ":D" & R).Select
                Selection.Copy
                Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                st1.Cells(R, C).Offset(0, 2).Value = color
                st1.Cells(R, C).Offset(0, 1).Value = colorcost
            End If
        Next prodColor
                    For Each prodColor In prodColors
            If prodColor.Value = "PGX" Then
                color = prodColor.Value
                colorcost = prodColor.Offset(0, 1).Value
                st1.Range("A" & R & ":D" & R).Select
                Selection.Copy
                Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                st1.Cells(R, C).Offset(0, 2).Value = color
                st1.Cells(R, C).Offset(0, 1).Value = colorcost
            End If
        Next prodColor
    End If
Next item

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help you:

```
Sub productsPrice()

    Dim st1, st2 As Worksheet
    Set st1 = Sheets("sheet1")
    Set st2 = Sheets("sheet2")
    Dim items As Range
    Set items = st1.Range(st1.Range("A2"), st1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    Dim item As Range
    For Each item In items
        Dim cost As String
        Dim code As String
        Dim t As String
        cost = item.Offset(0, 1).Value
        code = item.Offset(0, 2).Value
        t = item.Offset(0, 3).Value
        If cost <> "-" Then
            MsgBox (item & ", " & cost & ", " & code & ", " & t)
        Else
            Dim prodPos As Range
            Dim prodColors As Range
            Dim prodColor As Range
            Set prodPos = st2.Cells.Find(What:=code, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            Set prodColors = Range(prodPos.Offset(1, -1), prodPos.Offset(2, 4))
            Dim index As Integer
            index = 0
            For Each prodColor In prodColors
                If index Mod 2 = 0 Then
                    MsgBox (prodColor & ", " & prodColor.Offset(0, 1) & ", " & code & ", " & t)
                End If
                index = index + 1
            Next prodColor
        End If
    Next item

End Sub
```

Instead of MsgBox, just place the results in the appropriate place for you.

Comment: Thanks, this gives me a good framework. I will review and modify it a bit and probably post an update after I have worked on it. Appreciate it.